# RDLC Report hiding empty columns

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have a Tablix with a Column , i added this expression to show data in this column:

```
=Fields!PhoneNumber.Value & System.Environment.NewLine & Fields!Email.Value & System.Environment.NewLine & Fields!Address.Value
```

What i want is when one or more of the fields (PhoneNumber,Email,Address) is empty , the expression displays only non empty fields and does not put a new line

how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not throw-in IIF() to only add the new line IF a value is present

```
    =iif( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( Fields!PhoneNumber.Value ), '', Fields!PhoneNumber.Value & System.Environment.NewLine ) 
& iif( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( Fields!EMail.Value ), '', Fields!Email.Value & System.Environment.NewLine )  & Fields!Address.Value
```

Could get lengthy though.

Comment: It works now, i was making a mistake, Thank you very much you saved my life